# my postgres database crashes after certain manipulation of an audited table raw

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, microservices, audit, hibernate-envers

I get this error:

Internal Server Error

javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not extract ResultSet
...
connection was terminated due to conflict with recovery
Detail: User was holding a relation lock for too long.
...
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not extract ResultSet

Answer (score 1):

You must have run something like `DROP/ALTER TABLE`, `TRUUNCATE`, `LOCK`, `CLUSTER` and similar commands that require an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table on the streaming replication primary, or autovacuum truncated a table there. Such a lock is replicated and conflicts with any query running on that table on a standby server. Once `max_standby_streaming_delay` is exceeded, the query is canceled.

[Here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/streaming-replication-conflicts-in-postgresql/) is some background information.